# Reading .dat file and separating columns by "|" python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, file

I am trying to read the 0th column in my .dat file in python. The file column is split by "|".

For example:

```
lalaland   |   La2   |  It's a good day   |   Blah
```

I have the following to read the data and split columns by "|"

```
ref = pd.read_csv('DataBase.dat',sep="|")
```

The output is:

```
lalaland\t\t\t  ...                         \tBlah
0    happy\t\t\t\t  ...                       \tDescription A
1    good\t\t\t\t  ...                       \tDescription B
```

When I try to access the data via `ref[0:]` The 1st row of data is outputted instead of the 0th column.

How can I access the data only in the 0th column and put it in an array?

Comment: Are you sure the columns are separated by `|`? That output looks like it uses TAB separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
ref.loc[:,ref.columns[0]]
```

or

```
ref.iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: For additional info see: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-access-a-column-in-a-dataframe-using-pandas

Comment: That works. The output looks like "lalaland\t\t\t". How can I remove the "/t/t/t" from the data?

Comment: I got it! Just had to add ".str.strip()" Thank you @Naveed